# Google iOS SDK: Polyline skipping waypoint

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-polyline

I have a map section built into my app. It reads a custom built calendar and gets events from the selected day of that calendar, the event is an object and has properties to include address and lat/long. I'm able to drop a marker on the map using the lat/long but for some locations, when I pass them to the Google Directions API, the returned polylines skips them. As an example:

This address: 1003 Mill Pond Ln Ste B

[image: Marker Example]

The marker is dead on because I used lat/long. But when I get the polylines back this address is skipped:

[image]

I've checked the URL string being sent to the Directions API and the address is accurate (to what I am getting from the data source). My guess is that the ending part of that address Ste B is throwing off the API and because it can't resolve for it, it doesn't provide route data to that point.

So, I am just wondering if my suspicions are true and if so is there any work around I can do? (In general, not just for this one instance).